# How to scroll inside moving widget?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have moving widget and I want to have scrolling content inside that widget.
I put SingleChildScrollView and my content inside is scrolling but now widget is not moving

This is how widget its moving:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AKRTC.png)

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ytW8F.png)

[image]

I want to start scrolling content inside when widget is in upper position like on screen 2.

How to do it?

Here is my code for this widget:

```
return Builder(builder: (context) {
      final handle = GestureDetector(
        onVerticalDragUpdate: (details) {
          valueListener.value = (valueListener.value +
                  details.delta.dy / (context.size!.height / 2))
              .clamp(0.25, 0.89);
        },
        onTap: () {
          print(valueListener.value);
          if (valueListener.value >= 0.5) {
            valueListener.value = 0.25;
          } else {
            valueListener.value = 0.88;
          }
        },
        child: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            boxShadow: [
              BoxShadow(
                color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
                    ? Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.5)
                    : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                spreadRadius: 5,
                blurRadius: 7,
                offset: const Offset(0, 3),
              ),
            ],
            gradient: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.dark
                ? const LinearGradient(
                    colors: [Color(0xff061629), Color(0xff03101F)],
                    begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                    end: Alignment.bottomCenter)
                : null,
            color: Theme.of(context).brightness == Brightness.light
                ? Colors.white
                : null,
            borderRadius: !isExpanded
                ? BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(size.width * 0.1))
                : BorderRadius.vertical(
                    bottom: Radius.circular(size.width * 0.1)),
          ),
          height: size.height * 0.415,
          width: size.width,
          child: Stack(children: [
    ***** more code ****
); //GestureDetector
return AnimatedBuilder(
        animation: valueListener,
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Align(
            alignment: Alignment(0, valueListener.value * 2 - 1),
            child: child,
          );
        },
        child: handle,
```

To scroll my content inside that moving widget I wrapped Stack widget with SingleChildScrollView

Comment: Can you provide more code? Where are the image and the Maps Activity placed?

Comment: Image and Maps are two other widgets, I don't think is needed to show code responsible for them.

Comment: It is not. But they have to be placed inside the SrollView, too! If they are placed outside the scroll view, their view is independent of the ScrollView, therefore, they won't move when you scroll.

Comment: No, I don't want to scroll map and image, only contenf of this white Container with Text and Buttons

Comment: I can't see your ScrollView's children and parent. Can you share that? They should be something like this: Container -> stack-> [ image, maps, your floating container] and inside your floating container-> some bound height -> ScrollView . If you want your headlines and bottom bar to be static, do this: your floating container -> column -> [static box 1, static box 2, _container] and _container is ->bound height, scroll view

Comment: @Miro I wrapped Stack with SingleChildScrollView

Comment: but where is this Stack placed and what is inside it? Your image and Maps Activity **shouldn't** be inside of it since the stack is inside a ScrollView

Comment: @Miro You have stack in provided code. Image and Maps are in separated widget. 
In Stack I have all code for this text and buttons